# Stack window shows no output when debugging Redis Lua scripts with ZeroBrane

Tags: lua, redis, zerobrane

I have followed this tutorial to debug Redis Lua scripts.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mlajCj4QPw

Everything works except for that the Stack window shows no output so I can't see the value of the variables which is what I need to debug. If I change the Lua interpreter to something else than redis, and try to debug some normal Lua code then it works, and stack window shows everything. But once I switch to Redis as Lua interpreter then nothing shows on the Stack window.

I load up the redis.lua plugin from this repository
as suggested in the video:
https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage

Stack Window is empty as you can see:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Also for some reason when I enter GET foo in the remote console it says:

"Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script"

[image]

Since I have redis running on another machine, I thought perhaps I had to change some settings:

```
debugger.hostname = "192.168.0.161"
debugger.port = 8172
```

When I try to run it it says:

Can't connect to the debugger at '192.168.0.161:8172': connection refused

[image]

Do I have to do something special to the redis settings on my Virtual Linux Box to remote debug Redis? I am using Windows 7 so I can't install Redis 3.2 on it to debug so I have to run it on Cent OS 7 on VirtualBox.

Comment: What version of ZeroBrane Studio are you using? There have been several improvements in Stack handling in v1.60 and v1.70, so you may want to upgrade and check.

Comment: Placeholder for me :)

Comment: Using version 1.70; MobDebug 0.72. I downloaded the software today for Windows. I am using Windows 7. I also downloaded the redis plugin today, so that is also up to date. Redis version is 3.2.11. Running redis on VitualBox Cent OS 7.

Comment: I added a picture of the stack window while running the debugger.

Comment: Btw the only packages I have in the package folder are: sample.lua, and redis.lua

Comment: I tried this realtimewatches package: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/real-time-watches-plugin-zerobrane-studio. It works if I choose Lua interpreter as Lua 5, on some other files, but not if I select Lua interpreter as Redis.

Comment: Itamar Haber (lunatic^^) which version of ZeroBrane and redis plugin are you using here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mlajCj4QPw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these issues (empty stack window and an error on Redis commands in console) should be fixed in the updated version of Redis plugin (0.33).

Comment: Also does it matter if I am using redis that runs on another machine? Do I have to do some settings change for that? Or should the Stack Window show output regardless?

Comment: I already pushed the update: https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/redis.lua.
It doesn't matter where you run the redis instance as long as the computer with the IDE and the redis instance can communicate over socket.