# Getting error: Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script

Tags: lua, redis

I wanted to test out Lua scripting with Redis but I keep getting error messages for the simplest commands.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Why does this simple command say that I don't provide enough arguments?

Comment: It would help to know what version of Redis you are using.

Comment: I am using Redis 3.2.11. The error dissappeared for some reason. Don't know why.

Comment: The code in your screenshot is missing is comma (',') between the last two arguments (0 and -1) given to ZRANGE

Comment: That is true, thank you!

Comment: Itamar Haber I watched your video on youtube, thank you so much for the tutorial. By the way do you know why the Stack window is empty when I debug? I posted the problem in another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error running this code on a pre-release of v3.2:

```
redis.call("ZADD", "user", 1, "one")
return redis.call("ZRANGE", "user", 0, -1)
```

I get `one` printed to the Output window. I do get the same error if I skip one of the parameters in ZADD or ZRANGE calls, for example when trying to run `redis.call("ZADD", "user", 1)`.

Comment: By the way do you get stack window to show information? I have issues with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251176/stack-window-shows-no-output-when-debugging-redis-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane?noredirect=1#comment81455786_47251176

Comment: I answered in that question.